# Collection view inside table view

Tags: swift

I have the following problem.
In my project I have a table view with multiple sections and one row in every section. Inside row I have a collection view.
Collection view items count depending on section in which the collection is located.But I do not understand how to access section number when I call func numberOfItemsInSection for collection view.

Here is my code:

ViewController.swift

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { 
return data.count
}
```

TableCell.swift

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //TODO ?????? How can i get here section of table view
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have only one row in sections and have only one `UICollectionView` in every row, why don't you use just one `UICollectionView` to populate your data.

[link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9477-uicollectionview-tutorial-reusable-views-selection-and-reordering)

This is a long tutorial but maybe can help you to use `UICollectionView` effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array in UITableViewCell subclass and use that array in collectionview datasource methods

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    var collectionData = [String]()

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return collectionData.count
    }
}
```

In `tableView cellForRowAt` method assign value to the array and reload colletion view

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as? CustomCell
    cell?.collectionData = []//assign data here based on indexPath.section
    cell?.collectionView.reloadData()
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: thanks, works!
But but after reload data in collection view, those rows that on the screen when app launch does not apply collection view layout:(

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use object oriented approach, in Your tableview cell create a variable `tableSectionNumber`. Like

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    public var tableViewSectionNumber: Int = 0;
....
```

Now here in collectionView `numberOfItemsInSection` method, you can access it

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//TODO ?????? How can i get here section of table view
  self.tableViewSectionNumber // its here
 }
```

Now you can set this value in the cell in your ViewController, when you are populating the cell in TableView `cellForRowItem` method, Like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourCell
    cell.tableViewSectionNumber = indexPath.section // here you set the section number in cell
}
```